# Output classification predictions to CSV in Weka--where is output file saved?

Tags: weka

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130005/weka-predictions-to-csv) explain how to output classification predictions to CSV in Weka in both Weka 3.6 (right / option-click model and then save predictions) and 3.7 (choose more options and select Output predictions).

In Weka 3.7, I chose more options, selected Output predictions, and chose CSV as the specific type of output. An answer suggests to "Click on 'outputFile' and select a folder and type a filename." However, I cannot see 'outputFile' or where the CSV output is saved.

Where is the output file saved, or how can I click on 'outputFile' to name the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Weka 3.7.12 on OSX, I was able to find 'outputFile' and the other options by clicking on the whitebox containing **CSV** (after choosing CSV first), much like how you specify the options for certain classifiers by clicking on those whiteboxes. For me I wasn't able to type a filename, but if I created a blank file manually, I was able to correctly save the output the predictions to that file.

Answer (score 1):

If I left click on CSV (once I've selected it first), WEKA allows me to select an existing CSV file to save the predictions